# Changing the selected Vaadin tab on the client side

Tags: java, javascript, silverlight, gwt, vaadin

In order to simplify (and make 'prettier') navigation in a site I am buildilng, I am making a Silverlight component which will allow users to change the selected tab in a Tabsheet.  I noticed an option for hiding the tabs of a tabsheet (`tabsheetName.hideTabs()`).

Is there a way to change the selected tab using Javascript?  If so, my Silverlight navigation component can execute the Javascript.

The only other thing I can think of is to write a custom GWT component.  The Vaadin manual explains how to do this but it does not look trivial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating a generated mouse click event using JS and firing that on the tab element.

You’ll of course need the reference to the correct DOM element, but using a debugId for the TabSheet should make it possible.